# How to strain when bottling

Tags: bottling

I have small seeds in my primary and I am ready to bottle it. How do I strain out the little seeds before bottling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a siphon with a cap on the tip, the end that goes into the beer.

If the seeds are small enough that you think they'll slip through the cap, you can put a hop sock, cheesecloth, or other filter on the end of the siphon in the beer. Make sure to sanitize anything you use.

But if the seeds aren't suspended in the beer, are either floating on top or settled at the bottom, then I wouldn't worry about it. If you're careful they won't get into the siphon.

What kind of seeds are they? Hops? Fruit?

Comment: I have no idea where the little seeds came from. I think from the whole hops. The seeds were floating on the top of the beer. I siphoned it out and almost all of the seeds stayed behind. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Yeah, whole hops have little seeds sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid possibly oxidizing your beer, be sure that whatever filter medium you use is on the end of the siphon that's the "input", below the beer.  If you put it on the "output" side, you may oxidize the beer as it goes into the bottle.

Comment: Good point, Denny. I edited my answer to be more explicit about which end of the siphon should be filtered.